# Yii2 whenClient validation issue

Tags: conditional-statements, yii2, rule, required

For some reason I cannot get conditional rule 'required' to work. Even if I reduce the condition to "always return false", required-validation seems to check this unnecessary field:

```php
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['order_id', 'product_id', 'quantity'], 'required'],

        ['product_date', 'required', 
         'whenClient' => "function(attribute, value) {
                              return false;
                          }"
        ],  

       // more rules here
        [['date_create', 'date_update', 'product_date'], 'safe'],
        // more rules here
    ];
}
```

On form submit save() fails and $model->getErrors() points to product_date as a necessary field. What have I missed? Thank you in advance.

Comment: sure what i need is a more complex client-side check, i just can't get why it is not working in the simplest possible situation..

Answer (score 3):

You should add the server-side condition to the rule as well (documentation: [when](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html#$when-detail)):

```php
['product_date', 'required',
 'when'       => function ($model) {
                     return false;
                 },
 'whenClient' => "function(attribute, value) {
                      return false;
                  }"
],
```

`whenClient` is only for JS on the client side. When the form gets submitted the validation has to be done (or skipped) at the server as well. Usually you should have a `when` definition if you have `whenClient` definition. The `when` definition is much more important, `whenClient` is just to improve the user experience.

Find more infos [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#conditional-validation).

Comment: Thanks, robsch. But can I somehow skip server-side validation and still use client-side? or, if I use 'whenClient' I MUST use 'when' as well (and not just return 'true' in it, delegating validation to 'whenClient', but actually validating users input)?

Comment: I think you can use `whenClient` without `when` but I don't know why you would like to do that. Client validation is not secure, as you probably know. Anyway, the current behaviour is as expected: The client does not check product_date (because of `whenClient`). If the field is empty in the browser and is sent to the server, which has NO `when`, the required-validator marks this as error. But if there IS a `when`definition, working like `whenClient`, you get no validation error since required is overridden.

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
['product_date', 'required', 

    'whenClient' => "function(attribute, value) {
        return false;
    }"
    ],
```

With

```
['product_date', function(attribute, value) {
        return false;
    }],
```

Comment: Nope, `function(attribute, value) {return false;}` is a JS-code and therefore must be enclosed in a string.