# Yii2 client side validation refreshes the page on form submit

Tags: yii2

I am trying to perform client side check but the page is being refreshed. My rules looks like:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['email'], 'required'],
            [['email','cron'], 'string'],
            [['email'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
            [['cron', 'group', 'type'], 'integer'],
            [['email'], 'unique'],
            ['group', 'required', 'when' => function($model){
                return $model->type == 1;
            }, 'whenClient' => 'function(attribute, value){
                return 1==2;
            }']
        ];
    }
```

The form `enableClientValidation` is switched to true like this :

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                    'enableClientValidation' => true
                ]) ?>
```

Where is my mistake ? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to `enableAjaxValidation` too.

Comment: Thank you! Works now :) You gave the right answer first, so if you make it votable will give the points to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `enableAjaxValidation` property of `AcitveForm`:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
   'id' => 'form-id',
   'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
]);
```

**Controller**

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        return $this->asJson(ActiveForm::validate($model));
    }
}
```

[Yii2 Ajax Validation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation#ajax-validation)

[asJson()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-controller#asJson()-detail)

Comment: Somehow the page is still being refreshed. The record is not saved in db because the validation doesn't pass obviosly but error message doesn't show itself.  `1==2` the condition is alway false so I should see error message and have to stay on the same page, right ? I think it doesn't connect to the `whenClient` part.   Thank you!

Comment: @TomaTomov [Helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407380/yii2-difference-of-when-and-whenclient) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071890/yii2-whenclient-validation-issue) and [Issue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/12705)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                    'id' => 'form',
                    'enableAjaxValidation' => true
                ]) ?>
```